# How do I put a keyPress handler that can be used without having the button on focus?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, focus, handler, keypress

I'm doing a ReactJS calculator, and I want to be able to click the numbers on my keyboard and that showing on my calculator. I wrote the following handler:

```
handleKeyPress = (e) => {
  const element = this.state.keys.find(obj => obj.keyCode === e.keyCode);
  console.log(element);
  console.log(e); }
```

The content is just to check if it works. It doesn't work, and it took me some time to notice it only workes when a button (where I previously called the handler) is focused (after I clicked it). How can I make my handler work without any button being on focus? I want it to be called when I press any key.

Here is my app: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/AldanaBRZ/javascript-calculator?file=/src/App.js

Comment: you need to add a listener to the window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code allows you to catch any key you press:

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
    var keyPressed = e.key;
    console.log(keyPressed);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the calculator is the only thing in the page,  the easiest way to solve this is to put the handler for keyPress on the div that covers the whole page.  You'll have to refactor some of your other code to get it to work however.

Comment: It would be helpful to include sample code in your answer.